# Is it possible to record and auto-generate mock code in Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, jvm, mockito

Currently I'm dealing with legacy code and want to build a regression test around it to be sure everything is still the same as before.

To build it from ground up is too much work in this case so I played with the thought of letting mock code be auto-generated by a recorder.

Is there something like that (and also in stable)?

Answer (score 0):

There' a five star intellij plugin [Mockito code generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7901-mockito-code-generator)

which will generate the Mockito code by click Ctrl+Shift+M

> Auto-generated are:
>
> - RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) annotation for the class
> - Mocked fields for each non-static object declared in the test subject
> - Field for the test subject with @InjectMocks annotation
> - static imports for useful mockito functions like when, verify

Comment: thanks for the tip! but i think it doesn't really "record" things. for some stuff you'd really need the runtime behaviour in order to mock it...
furthermore: it seems not to be installable via the default repository when you try to install it via intellij idea?